# Invoking ASP.NET MVC Action from within another controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action Foo. From within Foo I need to pass a GUID to another action called Index. how can I do that?

```
public ActionResult Foo() {

   return View("Index",someguid); 

} 

 public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Not a whole lot of information to go from but how about `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = someguid });`?

Comment: Just call it as `return Index(someguid);`? (Which might be telling you that you are missing some object/service to provide the shared behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Precisely what the [RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) method is for.

As Dom mentioned in the comments, this should get you going in the right direction.

```
public ActionResult Foo() {

   return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = someguid });

}
```